Who represented Myanmar at the 10th anniversary of the BRI, relative to other countries?
US-sponsored Radio Free Asia commented last year:

But as the BRI prepares to celebrate its tenth anniversary at a summit in Beijing in October, China, unhappy with the slow pace of CMEC implementation, looks unlikely to extend an invitation to Min Aung Hlaing, denying him the recognition that he covets.

Who ultimately was invited to that summit, both from Myanmar and other Belt and Road countries? I.e. was Myanmar represented at a lesser level than other countries participating in the BRI?

AFAICT, Putin attended but I'm not sure where to get a full list.

So we know it was not Myanmar's top dude https://thediplomat.com/2023/10/which-world-leaders-came-to-chinas-3rd-belt-and-road-forum/ :  Of the Southeast Asian states who didn’t send top leaders this year, Malaysia, Myanmar, and the Philippines had attended the previous two forums.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: interesting article. You could easily write an answer based on that. Interpretation might be less straightforward. Maybe Hlaing was pissed at China for supporting some rebel groups, IDK. At least some other leaders mentioned probably didn't attend because of their [other] gripes with China.

Well, no it doesn't say who did.  There is Chinese coverage of the event, but with 140 odd attendees they will easily have airbrushed mentions of Myanmar if they feel the subject embarrassing, unless it is an expressly complete list.  That's it on my research, I was mostly seeing if Bing could be coaxed to be more useful than Google which is increasing disappointing these days.
